# DSUB9 maximum signal speed

Tags: connector, interface

Is there a practical limit to how fast a data transmission can be run over a DSUB9, SMD male to ribbon cable female? An engineer from a large connector manufacturer once told me that the insertion loss would be huge at higher speeds with a DSUB. Unfortunately I don't remember which speeds we were talking about.

Comment: How about a link for the terminally lazy like me?

Comment: Sorry, link to what? Me being both lazy and slow.

Comment: The DSUB9 and ribbon cable possibly indicating how the earth / ground is taken thru the DSUb

Comment: Andy, a DSUB9 is a standard connector, and it is often terminated to a ribbon cable. There are no predefined grounds or pinouts associated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

D-sub connectors are not really any worse than 0.1" headers in terms of signal integrity. With a bit of care in terms of how you assign grounds and signals to pins, they can easily handle hundreds of MHz. For example, I have successfully passed high-speed USB signals through both kinds of connectors.

As another example, consider the standard VGA connector, which is simply the "high-density" (3-row) form of a D-sub connector — it passes analog signals with bandwidths of hundreds of MHz quite successfully.

Note that you can get D-sub connectors with custom contacts, including coaxial contacts, for the ultimate in signal integrity. These are good well into the GHz range.

Comment: Usually for high-speed stuff, you interleave your signals with ground connections in the ribbon cable. Many of those ribbon cables can hit 110 ohm characteristic impedance reasonably well, so you should be fine up to 500 MHz if you're careful with your termination.